# How do I select specific vertices in blender using python script?

Tags: python, vertices

I have created a plane and have applied loop cut and slide twice horizontally and once vertically( using python script).

With this done, I intend to select the top two corner vertices using python script.

The image of the model can be viewed in the following link,

[image]

I browsed through net and found a code for selecting faces. So I figured, I would try the same with vertices. The code snippet is below,

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
obj.data.vertices[0].select = True # I TRIED THIS WITH ALL VALUES LIKE 0,1..
```

But, the result though no error did not give me the expected output.All Vertices remain unselected.

Please help me with solving this.

Comment: Even though I answered the immediate question, it might not be useful to you in the greater scheme of writing a python script. If you have more questions please _edit_ your question or ask a new one separately.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is probably counter-intuitive but you should place the Object in OBJECT mode when doing selection using indices via Python. Then flip back to EDIT mode to see the result.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj.data.vertices[0].select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```

Another way to make selections is to use BMesh, you'll find templates for this in
*TextEditor -> Templates -> Python -> Simple Bmesh (edit mode)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I don't understand the logic though.

Comment: just remember that setting the selections using indices on `data.vertices` only works in `OBJECT` mode. or else you have to use a `bmesh`.

Comment: I can't get this to work in 2.8. Does anyone know what are the relevant API changes and how to achieve this in 2.8?

Answer (score 8):

**Flush the selection**

Similarly to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/188312/15543 can set the selection of all the geometry in object mode, to avoid one edit mode toggle (*For edit mode `bmesh` is the way to go* see below)  to deselect.

A collections `foreach_set` is a quick way to set the properties of all items using a flat (or ravelled) list.

By default, all the geometry of a new primitive is selected. Deselecting verts using code may not flush the selection of edges and faces.

Example below, adds a plane in object mode, deselects all geometry but that of vertex index 0.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
# object mode
if context.object:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set()
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
#deselect all faces
me.polygons.foreach_set("select", (False,) * len(me.polygons))
# deselect all edges
me.edges.foreach_set("select", (False,) * len(me.edges))
# select only vert 0
me.vertices.foreach_set(
        "select",
        [not i for i in range(len(me.vertices))]
        )
        
  
me.update() # might not need.
# choose a selection mode
#context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True, True, True)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

**Same result using bmesh**

If working in edit mode, strongly recommend the use of an edit mode bmesh to make selections.

As before: Adds a plane, enters edit mode, selects vert 0.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(
        enter_editmode=True)
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
for i, v in enumerate(bm.verts):
    v.select_set(not i)
bm.select_mode |= {'VERT'}
bm.select_flush_mode()
    
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: interesting to use this foreach_set not only with numpy

Answer (score 4):

@z01ks The following worked for me in 2.8 (following from @zeffii 's answer):

```py
import bpy

#clear scene, make mesh
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(1.5708, 1.5708, 0))
obj = bpy.data.objects["Plane"]

#select vertex
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj.data.vertices[0].select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```

However, I am not especially happy with `obj.data.vertices[0].select = True`. The changelog explicitly states that they are transitioning to getters/setters for selection, but running `dir` on `obj.data.vertices[0]` reveals that `select` is the only way to do it, unless there is a completely different way now...

Comment: How do you select edges or faces. It's not working.

Comment: Edges and faces can also be selected. See the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71423190/blender-python-api-vertices-edges-and-faces-selection