# how to selectively show indices as developer

Tags: interface

One can choose to "show indices" of the vertices of a mesh when in edit mode.  However, when there are a lot of them, you can no longer read individual ones, it becomes a giant cloud of indices.  I would like assistance in coding an add-on that would allow one to add a boolean value to indices that you define (if defining them in python), so that when, as developer, you request to "show indices", only those indices that you've indicated you are interested in are the ones that get marked.  Perhaps this functionality exists already?  If it doesn't, help in finding the code of the existing functionality would go a long way to helping determine how easy or hard this will be..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not directly, what you asked for, but it may help anyway:

Only the indices of selected vertices are displayed. You may write an add-on, that selects only the vertices with certain indices to achieve what you want to.

Comment: yup, that would do it..   -the main difference with such an add-on is that the code would have to be changed in two places.  I'd have to have my main code, then a separate code to select the vertices..  so, ... vertex selection code..

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43127/how-do-i-select-specific-vertices-in-blender-using-python-script

Comment: You do not necessarily need to change your code at two places. Instead you have other options:
- You could save the interesting vertices in a vertex group and use the vertex group for selection.
- If you would like to operate on the indices of the vertices, you may save them e.g. in a list in an ID Property of the parent object of the mesh. The selection code could then evaluate this list.