# Python: How to select new center vertices after using poke face?

Tags: python, vertices

I'm trying to select just the new vertices after using poke face, this is what I have so far, but it doesn't work if I use poke on multiple connected faces. Any ideas?

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.poke()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='VERT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_less()
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43127/how-do-i-select-specific-vertices-in-blender-using-python-script

Answer (score 2):

**Use `bmesh`.**

Recommend using the `bmesh` module, to avoid mode toggling and other insanity.

Input the faces into the [`bmesh.ops.poke`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.poke) operator and it returns a dictionary of the newly created geometry. (faces and verts)

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context

ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

faces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]

poked = bmesh.ops.poke(
        bm,
        faces=faces,
        )
        
print("New verts", poked["verts"])
```

Answer (score 1):

you might try the return value of the operator

```
poked = bpy.ops.mesh.poke()
verts = poked['verts']
for v in verts:
    v.select = True
```

You could also do select in object mode:

```
verts = [v.index for v in verts]
for v in verts:
    ob.data.vertices[v].select = True
ob.data.update()
```