# How to select Edges marked as Seams in blender using Python script (not Shift+G)?

Tags: python, scripting, seams

I just want to write a python script to select edges which are marked seams using a python code instead of Shift+G, that is my request, I have to merge this code with a bigger one so Shift+G won't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think this should do the trick.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
  
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)

for e in bm.edges[:]:
    if e.seam:
        e.select_set(True)
        
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
```

Comment: There's no need to use `[:]` there to make a list copy, as you're not modifying the collection (as in the order or length doesn't change).

Comment: Thank you, Really thats all I wanted, appreciate that.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady good to know, Yeah I mainly learned everything I know about bmesh from this [demo in the bmesh docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html) and they use that semantic basically everytime they access the geo like that. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Jakemoyo it might be a good idea to get into the habit of using that to avoid nasty problems when you end up in the [state of sin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=1200&v=OSGv2VnC0go&feature=youtu.be), though I think it's nice to know why something is being done, and I'd also argue usually defensive programming is bad because it's better to fail and learn from that :). In your example you need to sum edges and verts, and BM sequences don't support addition operator, so instead list copies are made and added together.

Answer (score 2):

This will work in *Object Mode*:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C

for e in C.object.data.edges:
    e.select = e.use_seam
```

Or a faster way if you have a lot of geometry:

```py
import bpy, numpy as np
from bpy import context as C

me = C.object.data

array = np.zeros(len(me.polygons), dtype=bool)
me.polygons.foreach_set('select', array)
array = np.zeros(len(me.vertices), dtype=bool)
me.vertices.foreach_set('select', array)

array = np.zeros(len(me.edges), dtype=bool)
me.edges.foreach_get('use_seam', array)
me.edges.foreach_set('select', array)
```

Comment: Your code is really great and I am glad to see a new approach, But I have to give the answer of Jakemoyo as it's more closer to my need. Thank you tho,

Comment: @NamanDeep Sure, if you're in Edit Mode, Jakemoyo's answer is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object # make obj active object in your scene

if obj.type == 'MESH': # check if active object is a mesh (logical)

    # in order to select edges, you need to make sure that
    # previously you deselected everything in the Edit Mode
    # and set the select_mode to 'EDGE'
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type = 'EDGE')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
    
    # we need to return back to the OBJECT mode,
    # otherwise, the result won't be seen,
    # see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43127 for info
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

    # now we check all the edges
    for edge in obj.data.edges:
        if edge.use_seam: # if the edge uses seam
            edge.select = True # select it
        
    # as we did all selection in the OBJECT mode,
    # now we set to EDIT to see results
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 

else: 
    print("Object is not a mesh") # print if active object is not a mesh
```