# Selecting multiple vertices at a time with Python

Tags: python, vertices

My goal here is to select three vertices and manually create a face using bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add(). However, when I run the following code, no vertices are actually selected. I have been using this ([How do I select specific vertices in blender using python script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43127/how-do-i-select-specific-vertices-in-blender-using-python-script)) StackExchange question and answer to no avail. Sometimes my script will select one vertex, sometimes it will not. It never selects more than one. current_min_vert and the others are MeshVertex class objects, and should be equivalent to obj.data.vertices[n], where 'n' is any prescribed integer. Here is the code:

```
# Join meshes into one        
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.join()

# Set selection mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')

# Select vertices to form a triangle
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
current_min_vert_copy.select = True
current_min_vert.select = True
current_max_vert.select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```

The following image is my end goal. The top right vertex is current_min_vert_copy, the bottom right is current_min_vert, and the bottom left is current_max_vert.

[image: The end-goal.]

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you define `current_min_vert`? The problem might lie here.

Comment: @BlenderEnthusiast I define my current_max and current_min verts while looping through all the vertices of my mesh object. When I print out the value of current_min_vert and others, a MeshVertex class object is printed to the command window, indicating that Blender probably recognizes it as a vertex of my mesh.
current_max = np.abs(vertex.co.x); 
current_max_vert = mesh_object.vertices[i]

EDIT: My for loop was ill-formatted, so I replaced it with a simpler version.

Comment: Please always provide a minimal working example, otherwise it's hard to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender Python objects are short-lived and can be invalidated by various things like <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> undo or switching between *Edit* and *Object* modes…

Rather than assigning chosen vertices to your variables, assign their indices to your variables, and then change these lines:

```py
current_min_vert_copy.select = True
current_min_vert.select = True
current_max_vert.select = True
```

to

```py
me = D.objects["name_of_object"].data
me.vertices[current_min_vert_copy].select = True
me.vertices[current_min_vert].select = True
me.vertices[current_max_vert].select = True
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked!