# Blender crashes when translating mesh vertices in VS Code

Tags: python, mesh, vertices, transforms

I am writing a script that adds a cube, applies a subsurface modifier onto it and then randomly deforms that resulting mesh in order to get an irregular blob mesh. More precisely, I select a few mesh vertices and use the bpy.ops.transform.translate method to get smooth proportional deformations.

This below code works well when I run it in the Blender Scripting window. My problem arises when I transfer this same code to my script in VS Code. Most of the time it works without problems. But e.g. if I use it in a loop and create 100 such cubes after some random amount of deformed cubes Blender crashes (Error : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION) without further notice. It is weird that sometimes it crashes instantly when deforming the first cube, but most of the time it creates a couple of deformed objects and crashes then.

Does anyone have any advice?

````
#Create a cube, subdivide it, and make subdivision a mesh
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Subdivision"].levels = 3
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Subdivision")

#translate random mesh vertices using proportional edit
#i.e.: neighboring vertices are also translated proportionally
#extract mesh
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

context = bpy.context
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(context.edit_object.data)
#deselect all vertices
for v in bm.verts:
    v.select = False
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table() # NOTE: Necessary for accessing vertex list
for i in range(4):
    transform = Vector([random.uniform(-1, 1),
                random.uniform(-1, 1),
                random.uniform(-1, 1)])*TRANSLATION_RANGE
    v = bm.verts[random.randint(0, len(bm.verts) - 1)]
    v.select = True
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=transform, 
                            constraint_axis=(False, False, False),
                            orient_type='GLOBAL',
                            mirror=False, 
                            use_proportional_edit = True,
                            use_proportional_connected =True,
                            proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH',
                            proportional_size=PROPORTIONAL_SIZE)

# Enter Object Mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```
````

Comment: you're mixing bmesh edit mesh and bpy.ops... I'm quite sure that may cause memory conflicts.

Comment: I tried avoiding bmesh and using the obj.data.vertices of the active object, but then no vertices are translated. The resulting object stays undeformed.

Comment: Using bpy.data you've to deselect verts, edges and faces (not only verts). See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/188323/19156. Do it in object mode. And go to edit mode only for bpy.ops.transform.translate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I made the deformations work without making use of bmesh. However, Blender still crashes when I want to create more blobs. I can create even 1000 without problems directly in Blender Scripting. But when I use VS Code it crashes after a few created blobs.

Comment: I add no crash... but I'm not using vs code.